# Differentiate the function $v = \left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)^2$

Tags: derivatives

Differentiate the function
$$v = \left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)^2$$

I tries using the power rule, but it did not work out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you learned of the chain rule? $\frac d {dx} f(g(x)) = \frac{d f} {dg} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx}$

Comment: Just expand it.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :**
Chain rule says that :

$$\big(f \circ g\big)'=f'(g) \cdot g'$$

Therefore :

$$v' = 2\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)^{2-1} \cdot \left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)'=2\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac {1} {3x^{4/3}}\right)$$$$=\color{blue}{1-\frac{2}{3x^{5/3}}-\frac{1}{3x^{7/6}}}$$

**Method 2:** $$v = \left(\sqrt{x}+\frac 1 {x^{1/3}}\right)^2=x+\frac1{{x}^{2/3}}+2\sqrt x \frac{1}{x^{2/3}} $$

Therefore ;

$$v' = \left(x+\frac1{{x}^{2/3}}+2x^{-1/6}\right)' =\color{blue}{1-\frac{2}{3x^{5/3}}-\frac{1}{3x^{7/6}}}$$